# Appending an extra column based on a certain condition to a result query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have four columns generated based on the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client, Name, Email
FROM Login_Requests AS extR
INNER JOIN Login_Clients AS extC
    ON lower(extC.Name) = lower(extR.Client)
INNER JOIN Login_EmailDomains AS extED
    ON extED.ClientID = extC.ClientID
INNER JOIN Login_Admins AS extU
    ON extU.GroupID = extED.GroupID
WHERE extR.ReqStatusID = 2 AND extU.GroupID = 2;
```

It results in something like the following:

```
Client      Name         Email
-------     -----        ------
Google      Jon Snow     snowj@google.com
Google      Ned Stark    starkn@google.com
Apple       Bat Man      manb@apple.com
Apple       Cat Woman    womanc@apple.com
Microsoft   Bill Gates   gatesb@microsoft.com
```

However, I want to grab the admin from the `Login_Admins` table and append it to the result query as the last column like so:

```
Client      Name         Email                   Admin
-------     -----        ------                  ------
Google      Jon Snow     snowj@google.com        adminthefirst@shujin.com
Google      Ned Stark    starkn@google.com       adminthefirst@shujin.com
Apple       Bat Man      manb@apple.com          adminthesecond@shujin.com
Apple       Cat Woman    womanc@apple.com        adminthesecond@shujin.com
Microsoft   Bill Gates   gatesb@microsoft.com    adminthethird@shujin.com, adminthefourth@shujin.com
```

Like so. Essentially, there is one or even two admins that may be assigned to one client. I am currently having trouble writing the logic to append that admin column at the end of the result set. What I first attempted was maybe create a subquery like so:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT Login_Admins.Email
             FROM Login_Admins
             WHERE UserTypeID = 2 AND extED.GroupID = 2), ',', '')
```

And just adding it towards the end of the SELECT statement, but that ended up not working in my favor.
Is what I'm doing even possible because I'm at a loss at how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you need to use FOR XML to get it all on one line. The AdminEmails will return NULL if there aren't any, even with a CROSS APPLY so you might need to handle that if it's not supposed to be possible:

```
SELECT Client, Name, Email, adm.Admin
FROM Login_Requests AS extR
INNER JOIN Login_Clients AS extC
    ON lower(extC.Name) = lower(extR.Client)
INNER JOIN Login_EmailDomains AS extED
    ON extED.ClientID = extC.ClientID
CROSS APPLY
(   
        SELECT STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', ', extU.Email) 
        FROM Login_Admins AS extU
        WHERE extU.GroupID = extED.GroupID
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Admin
) AS adm
```

Comment: Looks pretty good, and I've never used a CROSS APPLY so this is interesting. However, the result of the AdminEmails column doesn't seem to be right. For example, for all rows, the AdminEmails column will have this: `snowj@google.com, starkn@google.com, manb@apple.com, womanc@apple.com, gatesb@microsoft.com`.

Comment: Does each client have their own GroupID or is the Login_Admins table also linked to Login_Clients? 

Also, try adding extU.Email instead of just 'Email' (I've amended the code above)

Comment: Each client has their own GroupID, it's their unique identifier. I think I solved it. Essentially, did you replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: I am currently in the process of analyzing your code. Are you able to explain to me what's happening in the cross apply?

Comment: The `CONCAT(', ', extU.Email)` function will generate you a list that looks like this:
`, one@email.com, two@email.com`

The `STUFF` function is then used to replace the first comma and space with an empty string hence this:

`SELECT STUFF(text, 1 [start at first character], 2 [characters to replace], '' )`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression along with other column in `SELECT` list like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client, Name, Email,
case when Login_Admins.UserTypeID = 2 AND extED.GroupID = 2 
then Login_Admins.Email else null end as Admin_Email
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have a quick question. Let's take my last row in the example where there's two admins for a row. Is there a way to coalesce it such that it will only be one row? Your code gives me two rows.

Comment: @Leon, NO, for that you need to use `XML Processing` ... `FOR XML PATH` and concatanate those multiple records. There are many examples present in SO which can help